# Jupyter notebook kernel not connecting StreamClosedError

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I installed anaconda, set up a Python 3.5 environment with tensorflow and jupyter. When I launch jupyter, it cannot connect to the python kernel, the error report looks like this:

```
425e-9aea-06b01371dfc3
[I 13:46:10.339 NotebookApp] Restoring connection for 142bbeaa-81b7-425e-9aea-06
b01371dfc3:0e8f3a6f35ae40e1bfc5ce602d2b29cf
[I 13:46:10.370 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for 142bbeaa-81b7-425e-9aea-06b0
1371dfc3:0e8f3a6f35ae40e1bfc5ce602d2b29cf
ERROR:asyncio:Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=WebSocketClosedError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\akubacki\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\test 3.5\lib\site-packa
ges\tornado\websocket.py", line 874, in wrapper
yield fut
File "C:\Users\akubacki\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\test 3.5\lib\site-packa
ges\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
value = future.result()
File "C:\Users\akubacki\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\test 3.5\lib\asyncio\fu
tures.py", line 294, in result
raise self._exception
tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError: Stream is closed
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
loops indefinitely from here on
```

I greatly appreciate any and all input!

Comment: I'm too facing similar issue. Any answer is appreciated.